# Ambiguous use of 'animate(withDuration:delay:options:animations:)'

Tags: swift, compilation, overloading

I've upgraded to the newly released Xcode 8, and this

```
let mediumInterval: TimeInterval = 0.6
UIView.animate(withDuration: mediumInterval) {
  print("test")
}
```

is giving me the error `Ambiguous use of 'animate(withDuration:delay:options:animations:)'` I really don't see what ambiguous here... All the `animate` functions declared in `UIView` are

```
open class func animate(withDuration duration: TimeInterval, delay: TimeInterval, options: UIViewAnimationOptions = [], animations: @escaping () -> Swift.Void, completion: (@escaping (Bool) -> Swift.Void)? = nil)

open class func animate(withDuration duration: TimeInterval, animations: @escaping () -> Swift.Void, completion: (@escaping (Bool) -> Swift.Void)? = nil)

open class func animate(withDuration duration: TimeInterval, animations: @escaping () -> Swift.Void)

open class func animate(withDuration duration: TimeInterval, delay: TimeInterval, usingSpringWithDamping dampingRatio: CGFloat, initialSpringVelocity velocity: CGFloat, options: UIViewAnimationOptions = [], animations: @escaping () -> Swift.Void, completion: (@escaping (Bool) -> Swift.Void)? = nil)
```

=== solution to get xcode to compile ===

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: mediumInterval, animation: {
  print("test")
}, completion: nil)
```

will compile,

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: mediumInterval, animation: {
  print("test")
})
```

will fail as before. I still don't get what's going on...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Where are you calling this? How is `Constants.mediumInterval` defined?

Comment: oups, sorry I missed that part. Thanks. I corrected `mediumInterval ` I don't think where I'm calling it helps explain the compilation error, but if does, I'm calling if from a method of class that inherits `UIViewController`

Comment: This error can sometimes be misleading. Comment out the animation and try to compile. See if it is actually that line.

Comment: Yes I've removed the animation for now and things compile fine.

Comment: I edited with a way to get xcode to compile, but that doesn't explains what's going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like PromiseKit, that I've been using, has an extension of UIView that defines a conflicting version of animate (https://github.com/PromiseKit/UIKit/blob/master/Sources/UIView%2BPromise.swift)

XCode was not able to show me where the two conflicting versions were coming from so it took me a while to catch it. I've reported the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error because I forgot to add an "s" to "animation".
So maybe :

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: mediumInterval, animation: {
  print("test")
})
```

won't compile because of that.